# Why is no TypeError raised when iterator function is called without iterating?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, typeerror

For an exercise learning Python I tried to make a float_range() iterator that imitates range() but allows for floats. I try to catch wrong numbers of arguments to raise a TypeError and wrote the function below.

```
def float_range(*args):
    
    start = 0.0
    step = 1.0

    if len(args) == 3: 
        start, end, step = args
    elif len(args) == 2:
        start, end = args
    elif len(args) == 1:
        (end,) = args
    else:
        raise TypeError()

    n = start
    if start < end:
        if step > 0: 
            while n < end:
                yield n
                n += step
    else:
        if step < 0:
            while n > end:
                yield n
                n += step
```

Now, I do not understand why `for n in float_range(1,2,3,4): print(n)` and `for n in float_range(): print(n)` raise a TypeError, but `float_range()` and `float_range(1,2,3,4)` do not.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code to see what happens in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `yield` keyword in your function the function will return a generator:

```
print(float_range())

<generator object float_range at 0x7fe714bc2f20>
```

It doesn't return error because you haven't iterated over it yet. The first time the `for` calls your generator object created from your function, it will run the code in your function from the beginning until it hits `yield`.

In your case, you don't have any parameters so `TypeError` exception is thrown.